# java string : preserve line breaks to pass to markdown4j

Tags: java, markdown, markdown4j

I am building a Java application that will use markdown syntax and convert to HTML. I am currently having an issue where I am unable to preserve the line breaks in a string necessary for markdown to recognize certain HTML markup. In this exmaple:

```
This is a heading
=======
```

comes out fine when

```
String html = new Markdown4jProcessor().process(mdTxtFile);
```

is reading from a file, but when you pass the `.process()` method a string, the line breaks are stripped and you get

```
<p>This is a heading=======</p>
```

in the output.

If I pass this string:

```
String txt = "hello, this is my heading \r=====\r and here is some text";
```

that parses correctly.

I have tried building the string in a number of different ways, reading a file, `String txt += newLine`, `StringBuffer`, etc.

This will work as a string passed from an HTML form as a param to a servlet.

This is the actual code that is doing the HTML conversion, the string is stored and retrieved out of a map prior to parsing:

```
String html = new Markdown4jProcessor().process(newText);
```

This is probably a pretty basic question, but my googling did not provide a simple answer.

Comment: You are saying "Comes out *fine* (...) when reading from a file" and "If I pass this string (...), that parses *correctly*". So what is the case that doesn't work as expected? If it is the second case: have you tried `\n` or `\r\n` instead of  `\r`?